# How can i get generated OTP to send

Tags: multi-factor-authentication

As you may be know the OTP code(Authenticator App) will be compared in LoginWith2fa action in IDS4 via

```
SignInmManager.TwoFactorAuthenticatorSignInAsync(...)
```

There is a question. how can I get generated OTP to send?
In my Scenario I want to Send it via SMS or Email but first of all i should access to the code.

Comment: Hi! IdentityServer is OpenID Connect, they don't really do the authentication part, for that you usually use Asp.NET Identity which is not the same thing. The `SignInManager` is part of it. Not Identity Server. Please take a look at ASP.NET Identity docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity

Comment: HI
thank you for response.
I knew that. The point is during login action we use it for complete the login cycle but my question is about TOTP|OTP code not how identityserver wired to asp.net identity.

Comment: You should then remove the identityserver4 tag, as this is not related to identityserver4 in any way. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity

Comment: thank you Pablo, do you know how to get the code from Asp.net Identity?

Comment: Sorry, the previous link pointed to old net framework documentation, this should be more relevant https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/mfa?view=aspnetcore-6.0, inside that link on the top you'll find a full application example of MFA using aspnetcore.